# Sharepoint and Active Directory Integration

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, user-profile-service

New to the whole Sharepoint business, so any help is appreciated.
Whenever a new user is created in Active Directory,
I'd like Sharepoint to automatically populate itself to add the entry as a contact.

How and where do I set up the LDAP lookup or automatically import AD details.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?  SharePoint Foundation does not include the User Profile Service Application or the ability to synchronize.

Answer (score 4):

You can have [User profile synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382639.aspx) and [schedule the synchronization incremental timer job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890103.aspx)  with the frequency you need.

Answer (score 0):

Spence's blog post is the best on the topic, all the background and then the specific how to: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx